# Why an array of pointers of derivative class objects not able to declare

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, inheritance

**Possible Duplicate of :**

[Creating an array of pointers of derivative class objects. C++. Abstract base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18472479/creating-an-array-of-pointers-of-derivative-class-objects-c-abstract-base-cl)

Here i am getting below error to define this type of class structure. Actually i want to access some extra methods of `KeyValue2` class which i define below. But i can only able to access `IKeyValue` class methods because here i cant able to make `KeyValue2` object pointers in `vectorKeyValue` Class.

Please check more details in code comment

Error : a value of type `"KeyValue2 **"` cannot be assigned to an entity of type `"IKeyValue **"`

**Code :**

```
class IKeyValue
{
    IKeyValue() {}
    virtual ~IKeyValue() {}
    virtual void setKey(int key) = 0;
    virtual void setValue(std::string value) = 0;
    virtual int getKey() = 0;
    virtual std::string getValue() = 0;
};

struct IVectorKeyValue
{
    // some methods with Virtual keyword and virtual destructor.
    IVectorKeyValue() {}
    virtual ~IVectorKeyValue() {}
    virtual void push_back(IKeyValue * item) = 0;
    virtual void pop_back() = 0;
    virtual IKeyValue * get(int index) = 0;
    virtual void set(int index, IKeyValue * item) = 0;
    virtual size_t size() = 0;
};

class KeyValue : public IKeyValue
{
public:
    // declare all methods of IKeyValue Base Class
    // This method is Extra Method, which i will use through derive class object
    std::string getValueIndex(int index);
    IVectorString* getVectorStringValues();
private:
    int key_;
};

class VectorKeyValue : public IVectorKeyValue
{

public:
    VectorKeyValue() : size_(0), capacity_(10)
    {
        vectorKeyValue_ = new KeyValue2 *[capacity_];
    }
    ~VectorKeyValue()
    {
        delete[] vectorKeyValue_;
        vectorKeyValue_ = NULL;
    }
   // declare all methods of IVectorKeyValue Base Class
private:
    size_t size_;
    size_t capacity_;
    IKeyValue **vectorKeyValue_;
};

int main()
{
    IVectorKeyValue *rootNode = new VectorKeyValue();
    // here I want to use some methods of KeyValue2 class, like getValueIndex and getVectorStringValues
    // But i cant use them. I do not know why.

    // getVectorStringValues method i am not able to access. because 
    // here rootNode->get(0) type is IkeyValue not KeyValue.
    rootNode->get(0)->getVectorStringValues();
    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: `IKeyValue **` and `KeyValue2 **` are not compatible. Your array needs a fundamental design fix. It can only contain pointers of type `IKeyValue *`, which may point to `KeyValue2` objects. Each `KeyValue2` will be allocated individually, not as an array.

Comment: It will make life a lot easier if you use `std::vector` instead of reinventing the wheel, and mayve even easier if you use `std::vector<std:;shared_ptr<IKeyValue *>>` .

Comment: @MattMcNabb I can not use vector, this is something about my assignment work. Please let me know how can i achieve this

Comment: change `new KeyValue2 *[capacity_];` to `new IKeyValue *[capacity_]();`. And either write or disable the copy-constructor and copy-assignment operator.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, a pointer to a pointer to a subtype is not implicitly convertible to a pointer to a pointer to a supertype. To see why, consider this:

```
SuperType super;
SubType * sub_ptr = NULL;
SuperType * * super_ptr_ptr = &sub_ptr;    // illegal
*super_ptr_ptr = &super;
```

Without this restriction, you could change `sub_ptr` to point to `super`, without any sort of explicit cast or other indication that a type-system violation is expected.

(This is the same reason that `T * *` is not implicitly convertible to `const T * *`, even though `T *` is implicitly convertible to `const T *`.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what thing i can change in my code so I can access methods which i want.

Comment: @Sam_k: Just change `IKeyValue **vectorKeyValue_;` to `KeyValue2 **vectorKeyValue_;`. Individual `KeyValue2 *`-s can be converted to `IKeyValue *`-s as required.

Comment: i did the same like this :`KeyValue **vectorKeyValue_` now this error gone. But after this as per my other virtual function definition i can not able to assign  input parameter to my pointer array  in some methods like : `void set(int index, IKeyValue * item)`

Comment: @Sam_k: Sure you can. `KeyValue2 *` is convertible to `IKeyValue *`.

Comment: But i checked, I cant able to do it. After a lot time i changed my method name and keep set method as empty in my cpp file. Is it good idea?
`void VectorKeyValue::setKeyValuePair(int index, KeyValue* item)
{
 if(index < size_ && index >= 0)
 {
  vectorKeyValue_[index] = item;
 }
}`

Comment: @Sam_k: The code you've posted in your comment is inconsistent with the code you posted in your question. (You keep talking about `KeyValue`, for example, even though that class does not exist in your question.) I suggest you put some effort into creating a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and post a new question.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Consider KeyValue2 as Keyvalue.

Comment: Updated in Question also

Comment: @Sam_k: No worries. I've moved on now. Good luck with your updated question. :-)

Comment: So My last comment is right or wrong? i have only one way to get it done. I just updated class name in question. Nothing more.